# will the micro-task queue or the macro-task queue run first?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, callstack, event-loop

i was reading an [article about Promises and the event queue](https://dev.to/lydiahallie/javascript-visualized-promises-async-await-5gke), and from what I understood, the event loop has a "micro-task queue" and a "macro-task queue".
[image: enter tasks table here]

and from that article is said that, the event loop will sort of run all of what's in the the "Micro-task queue" (promises..) and THEN, move on to running what's inside the "Macro-task queue" (setTimeout..), here is a [gif](https://res.cloudinary.com/practicaldev/image/fetch/s--05Fi8vBq--/c_limit%2Cf_auto%2Cfl_progressive%2Cq_66%2Cw_880/https://dev-to-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/i/42eatw03fcha0e1qcrf0.gif) explaining it better.

but then when i tested it in my text editor, it didn't do what i expected it to do, it ran the `setTimeout` first and THEN it ran the `the axios promise`, which means that the `macro task queue` got executed before the Micro-task queue.

here is my code:

[image: my code]

Comment: Understand that tasks of any type only run when they're actually in a queue. The Axios task won't be in the queue until the HTTP request completes.

Comment: @Pointy that really answered my question, thanks :))

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` adds an event to be executed in the macro task queue when the time (0 milliseconds in this case) elapsed, but `axios.get` sends a request which takes a while and the callback you passed to the `then` function will only be scheduled once the promise is fulfilled, which will be much later, maybe 200ms or so, which is an eternity in comparison to 0 milliseconds. Now, what actually happens is that your function finishes and looks for things to be executed in the micro task queue, but your callback passed to the `.then()` is not scheduled yet because the request is still pending, so it looks for macro task queue elements and finds the `setTimeout` callback and proceeds to execute it. Later on the request finished, the `.then()`'s callback is added to the micro task queue and then it will be picked up and executed accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

please refer this for micro and macro task

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3O1Lb.png)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).